# Magento 2.1 - custom administrator user attributes

Tags: magento-2.1

I googled a lot, but it's just not there !!

i need to add "mobile" and "photo" fields to the administrator users in magento 2.1.

how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple module, here I will assuming that you already know how to create a base module so I will skip that part.

In Vendor/ModuleName/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
    $setup->startSetup();

    $table = $setup->getTable('admin_user');

    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $table,
        'mobile',
        [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Mobile'
        ]
    );

    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $table,
        'photo',
        [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Photo'
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then when you run setup:upgrade, it will install the new columns into the table.

Comment: will this appear in the users administrator grid table ?

Comment: Yes it will! If this answer works out for you, please select it as an accepted answer so other people will see it.